# VMWare ESXi not recognizing usb keyboard on install

Tags: vmware-esxi, installation, usb, keyboard, hpe

We are currently attempting to install VMWare ESXi 5.5 on a HPE proliant DL380 gen10 server. The beginning boot sequence appears that it is running fine, but when we get to the first menu option requiring input, it is not accepting any input from the attached keyboard. We have tried changing the port that the keyboard is attached to as well as changing out keyboard(reboots between each of these operations), but no dice. Also, a side question, that version of ESXi is compatible with our hardware, right? This is my first time installing ESXi, working with our senior network admin, but we are both stumped. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What version is your ESXi installer? Version and build number? And why are you installing ESXi 5.5 on new hardware? The current revision is 6.5.

Comment: Version is 5.5 build is 2403361 I believe. It is the generic 5.5 u2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [VMware support matrix](http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/vmware.aspx#.WkOgTSPVSSs) doesn't show any official support for Gen10 HPE ProLiant systems under VMware ESXi 5.5.

Remember that the build you're using was released January 27, 2015 (which predates the introduction of the hardware)... So you're not even using the current ESXi 5.5.

I suspect that you may have RAID controller and other device driver issues. For the USB keyboard input, just use the ILO to to bypass the need for physical keyboards.

Please use the *HP-specific Build* of 5.5 (if you can't use a newer main version of VMware). It is located at: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=OEM-ESXI55U3B-HPE&productId=353

Comment: Thank you, we will try this and update as soon as we attempt.

Comment: We attempted installation using ILO still not working, its looking more and more like its a hardware compatibility issue, we also attempted using HP specific installation. Thank you for the quick response.